# Why only one jquery delegate() is work?

Tags: jquery, delegates, append

I have a problem with jquery delegate().
It's a form for adding new test questions and answers. But unfortunately delegate() isn't work for generated answer inputs. For adding new question it works good, but in generated answer not.

```
$(".questions").delegate(".qadd", "click", function() {
    $(".questions").after("<div class='newq'><br><div><input placeholder='Question' type='text'/><a class='qdel' href='#'>-</a></div><div class='answers'><input placeholder='Answer' type='text'/><a class='ansadd' href='#'>+</a><label class='richtig'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='Richtig'>True</label></div></div>");

    $(".qdel").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".newq").remove();
    });

});

$(".answers").delegate(".ansadd", "click", function() {
    $(".answers").first().after("<div class='newa'><input placeholder='Answer' type='text'/><a class='adel' href='#'>-</a><label class='richtig'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='Richtig'>True</label></div>");

    $(".adel").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".newa").remove();
    });

});
```

You can check my code here:
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w96ke9r9/)

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Note that `delegate()` is a very outdated method to be using. `on()` is considered much better practice.

Comment: @guradio it's https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: according to documentation `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method` from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) you can read further

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but on() is also not work :( can you please write me your example for me :/

Comment: @Ayaz I added an answer for you

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you need to register .ansadd event also..**

```
$(".questions").on('click', '.qadd', function () {
    $(".questions").after("<div class='newq'><br><div><input placeholder='Question' type='text'/><a class='qdel' href='#'>-</a></div><div class='answers'><input placeholder='Answer' type='text'/><a class='ansadd' href='#'>+</a><label class='richtig'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='Richtig'>True</label></div></div>");
})

$(document).on('click', '.qdel', function () {
    $(this).closest(".newq").remove();
});
$(document).on('click', '.ansadd', function () {
    $(this).after('<span>Do Whatever you want to do</span>');
});



$(document).on('click', '.adel', function () {
    $(this).closest(".newa").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have used another solution and it works but have a functional bug. http://create.az/extfiles/safe112/iframe/neue_test_2.html in this page, when I click to "+" for adding a question, it works good but when I want click and add answer input to question, it generate a 1x answer for each question. Normally it should generate answer only for one question.

Comment: you can achieve that using the solution above..add your html string and append that to traget

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `delegate()` is a very outdated method. You should use `on()` instead. To fix your issue, move the `click()` handlers out of the delegates and make those in to delegated event handlers too. Try this:

```
$(".questions").on('click', '.qadd', function() {
    $(".questions").after("<div class='newq'><br><div><input placeholder='Question' type='text'/><a class='qdel' href='#'>-</a></div><div class='answers'><input placeholder='Answer' type='text'/><a class='ansadd' href='#'>+</a><label class='richtig'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='Richtig'>True</label></div></div>");    
})

$(document).on('click', '.qdel', function() {
    $(this).closest(".newq").remove();
});

$(".answers").on('click', '.ansadd', function() {
    $(".answers").first().after("<div class='newa'><input placeholder='Answer' type='text'/><a class='adel' href='#'>-</a><label class='richtig'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='Richtig'>True</label></div>");    
})

$(document).on('click', '.adel', function() {
    $(this).closest(".newa").remove();
});
```

Note that for best performance you should change `$(document)` in the example above to the closest parent element to `.adel` and `.qdel` which are present in the DOM when the page loads. I only used it as an example as there was no other element you showed which would work in the question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was copied and tried your code, but question adding is work answer adding not :(

Comment: I would need to see your exact HTML to be able to diagnose any issues, but it seems to work in a test here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/csoo35rf/

Comment: I understood you friend, but I want use this "+", "-" buttons nearby inputs